# Kubuntu 22.04 LTS freezing while booting on [AE NOT FOUND] error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu

I have currently a dual boot windows 10 and kubuntu 22.04 Lts. Everything worked perfectly, Linux was working as well as windows but one day kubuntu stopped starting and I have no idea why.
As i have a starting freezed screen i actually don't know how to fixed it. I always had this same message error but it always worked fine before. I not sure it's actually related to my boot problem...

If someone can help me that would be awesome.

Comment: The "error" mentioned in the title is unrelated but you may want to update UEFI ("BIOS") anyway. Now, please [edit] the question and describe what really happens, "kubuntu stopped starting" says nothing useful.

Comment: I've had a similar sounding issue show up after windows did an update today. If you're using grub as the bootloader (you don't say, so just guessing), hold down `shift` while booting to bring up the grub menu, then select "Advanced options for Ubuntu", and pick an older kernel from the list. In my case, 5.15.0-48 works, whereas 5.15.0-50 isn't.